# Server-side push with Active Data Service in ADF

Tags: comet, ads, oracle-adf

I am developing an ADF Fusion Web application that contains a messaging module with JDeveloper 11.1.1.4.0. I searched the techniques to do server-side push (also asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12723403/how-facebook-intializes-recent-news-feed-entries-instantly) about it) I searched about "comet", server-side push, etc.
I found [Active Data Service](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/web.1111/b31974/adv_ads.htm) and some chat or server-side push examples:

- http://biemond.blogspot.com/2009/12/adf-data-push-with-active-data-service.html
- https://blogs.oracle.com/adffun/entry/building_a_real_time_twitter_client_with_adf

I follow the instructions in [biemond's blog](http://biemond.blogspot.com/2009/12/adf-data-push-with-active-data-service.html) do the configurations of ADS

added ads conf to adf-config.xml under ADF META-INF/services folder

```
<ads:adf-activedata-config xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/activedata/config">
    <transport>long-polling</transport>  
    <latency-threshold>10000</latency-threshold>  
    <keep-alive-interval>10000</keep-alive-interval>  
    <polling-interval>3000</polling-interval>  
    <max-reconnect-attempt-time>1800000</max-reconnect-attempt-time>  
    <reconnect-wait-time>10000</reconnect-wait-time></ads:adf-activedata-config>
```

and created adf-config.properties file

```
http\://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/activedata/config=oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.activedata.ActiveDataConfiguration$ActiveDataConfigCallback
```

and created a table in jsf page.

```
<af:table value="#{MessageModel}" var="row"
                rows="#{bindings.MessageVO.rangeSize}"
                emptyText="#{bindings.MessageVO.viewable ? 'No data to display.' : 'Access Denied.'}"
                fetchSize="#{bindings.MessageVO.rangeSize}"
                rowBandingInterval="0" id="t1">
        <af:column sortProperty="id" sortable="false"
                   headerText="#{bindings.MessageVO.hints.id.label}"
                   id="c1">
          <af:outputText value="#{row.id}" id="ot2">
            <af:convertNumber groupingUsed="false"
                              pattern="#{bindings.MessageVO.hints.id.format}"/>
          </af:outputText>
        </af:column>
        <af:column sortProperty="Title" sortable="false"
                   headerText="#{bindings.MessageVO.hints.Title.label}"
                   id="c2">
          <af:outputText value="#{row.title}" id="ot3"/>
        </af:column>
      </af:table>
```

And created MessageModel class which is used as table value in jsff.

```
public class MessageModel extends ActiveCollectionModelDecorator {  

 private MessageActiveDataModel activeDataModel = new MessageActiveDataModel();  
 private CollectionModel model = null;  


 public CollectionModel getCollectionModel() {
    if (model == null) {
        DCBindingContainer dcBindings = (DCBindingContainer)BindingContext.getCurrent().getCurrentBindingsEntry();  
        FacesCtrlHierBinding treeData = (FacesCtrlHierBinding)dcBindings.getControlBinding("MessageVO");  
        model = treeData.getCollectionModel();  
    }
    return model;
 }

 public MessageActiveDataModel getActiveDataModel() {
      return activeDataModel;
 }

 public MessageActiveDataModel getMessageActiveDataModel() {  
     return activeDataModel;  
 }  

}
```

and an ActiveDataModel class

```
public class MessageActiveDataModel extends BaseActiveDataModel {

private final AtomicInteger listenerCount = new AtomicInteger(0);
private final AtomicInteger currEventId = new AtomicInteger();

protected void startActiveData(Collection<Object> rowKeys,
                               int startChangeCount) {
    listenerCount.incrementAndGet();
    if (listenerCount.get() == 1) {
        System.out.println("start up");

        Runnable dataChanger = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("MyThread starting.");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                    System.out.println("thread running");
                    Change chg = new Change();
                    chg.triggerDataChange(MessageActiveDataModel.this);
                } catch (Exception exc) {
                    System.out.println("MyThread exceptioned out.");
                }
                System.out.println("MyThread terminating.");
            }
        };
        Thread newThrd = new Thread(dataChanger);
        newThrd.start();
    }
}

protected void stopActiveData(Collection<Object> rowKeys) {
    listenerCount.decrementAndGet();
    if (listenerCount.get() == 0) {
        System.out.println("tear down");
    }
}

public int getCurrentChangeCount() {
    return currEventId.get();
}

public void bumpChangeCount() {
    currEventId.incrementAndGet();
}

public void dataChanged(ActiveDataUpdateEvent event) {
    fireActiveDataUpdate(event);
}
```

}

the thread in ActiveDataModel class is triggers a class named as Change

```
public class Change {
public Change() {
}

public void triggerDataChange(MessageActiveDataModel model) throws Exception {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(4000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }
        model.bumpChangeCount();
        ActiveDataUpdateEvent event =
            ActiveDataEventUtil.buildActiveDataUpdateEvent(ActiveDataEntry.ChangeType.UPDATE,
                                                           model.getCurrentChangeCount(),
                                                           JboActiveDataEventUtil.convertKeyPath(new Object[] { new Long(1),
                                                                                                                new Integer(0) }),
                                                           null,
                                                           new String[] { "title" },
                                                           new Object[] { "Administration" });

        model.dataChanged(event);
    }
}
```

}

When I run the application, I can see the rows from MessageVO in the table. It enters model class, active data model class and change class, changes listenerCount and currentEventId values in ActiveDataMode class. When I update the rows in database, it does not trigger change event and does not detect the update in database.

Does anyone have any idea about how to listen the change in database and do a server-side push according to the db change in ADF?

Thanks in Advance.